# Contract storage needs nested orderbooks; best practice way to structure dapp?

Tags: ink, wasm

For my dapp I need storage which can reference a mutable amount of events, all of which have their own orderbook. Expanded, it looks something like this:

```
CoreStorage {
    coin_storage: CoinStore, //not the issue
    event_storage: {
        event_type_1: Mapping<EventId, EventType1>,
        event_type_2: Mapping<EventId, EventType2>,
    }

EventType1 {
    event_info: EventInfo,
    event_orderbook: EventOrderBook //where the issue lies
}

EventOrderbook {
    orders_0: Mapping<AccountId, Order>, //this is impossible from what I can tell
    orders_1: Mapping<AccountId, Order> 
}
```

Nested `Mapping` structures are not supported by design. Likely the final data structure will not be a `Mapping` type, something much more performant for sorted lookups, but regardless it will not be able to adhere to the `PackedLayout` trait (this is just what I assume with my current knowledge).

My only thought I have to make this work is to have a separate smart contract for every `EventOrderbook` that communicates back to the main smart contract, so the storage structure will be replaced with something like:

```
use event_contract::EventContract

EventType1 {
    event_info: EventInfo,
    event_contract: EventContract
}
```

and in another crate I would have a contract that is compiled as a dependency that I can instantiate when I instantiate this main contract.

Is this the correct approach? Or is there some more efficient way I should be doing this?

Thank you! Any help or documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As Mapping inside Mapping is not supported [explanation here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/how-to-have-a-mapping-in-a-custom-structure-inside-an-ink-contract/1668#1668).
The best way is to use a tuple:

If you have this structure:

```
Map<A, Map<B, C>>
```

You can structure it like this:

```
Map<(A, B), C>
```

In your example it can be:

```
EventType1 {
    event_info: EventInfo,
}

CoreStorage {
    coin_storage: CoinStore, //not the issue
    event_storage: {
        event_type_1: Mapping<EventId, EventType1>,
        event_type_2: Mapping<EventId, EventType2>,
        order_0: Mapping<(EventId, AccountId), Order>
        order_1: Mapping<(EventId, AccountId), Order>
    }
```

And then you can access `Orders` with `EventId` & `AccountId`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer, there is a possibility to use a different data-structure for nested-mappings. An easy to implement one is [BTreeMap](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_prelude/collections/btree_map/struct.BTreeMap.html). It is worth noting that `BTreeMap` is not as efficient as `Mapping`. See [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1099/2696) for details.

Here is an example implementation based on your code:

```
use ink_prelude::collections::BTreeMap;

CoreStorage {
    coin_storage: CoinStore,
    event_storage: {
        event_type_1: Mapping<EventId, EventType1>,
        event_type_2: Mapping<EventId, EventType2>,
    }

EventType1 {
    event_info: EventInfo,
    event_orderbook: EventOrderBook
}

EventOrderbook {
    orders_0: BTreeMap<AccountId, Order>,
    orders_1: BTreeMap<AccountId, Order> 
}
```