# How to nest mapping in ink (Rust) smart contract like solidity?

Tags: ink, substrate-contracts-node

I want to nest mapping in ink (Rust) smart contract like solidity:
`mapping(account_id => mapping(campaign_id => donate_value))`

Comment: See https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/contract-storage-needs-nested-orderbooks-best-practice-way-to-structure-dapp/3993#3993.