# How can I use complex structure in ink! version3

Tags: ink, smart-contract, wasm

how can i use the complex structure`(like Mapping<String, Vec<Map<String, String>>>)` in ink!

```rs
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]
mod mycontract {
    use ink_prelude::string::String;
    use ink_prelude::vec::Vec;
    use ink_storage::{traits::SpreadAllocate, Mapping};


    /// Defines the storage of your contract.
    /// Add new fields to the below struct in order
    /// to add new static storage fields to your contract.
    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
    pub struct Mycontract {
        /// 存储 key 对应的哈希值
        hash_value_map: Mapping<String, Vec<Mapping<String, String>>>,
    }

    impl Mycontract {

        /// 合约构造器，用于合约的初始化
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn default() -> Self {
            ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract(|_: &mut Self| {})
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn set_data(&mut self, key_value:String, data:i32) {
            match self.hash_value_map.get(&key_value) {
                None => {

                }
                Some(test) => {

                }
            }
            // match self.hash_value_map.get(&key_value) {
            //     None => {
            //         let mut vec:Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
            //         vec.push(data);
            //         self.hash_value_map.insert(key_value, &vec);
            //     }
            //     Some(mut vec) => {
            //         vec.push(data);
            //         self.hash_value_map.insert(key_value, &vec);
            //     }
            // }
        }
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get_data(&self, hash_key: String) -> Result<String,String> {
            // match self.hash_value_map.get(&hash_key) {
            //     None => {
            //         return Err(String::from("DATA_NOT_FOUND"))
            //     }
            //     Some(vec) => {
            //         return Ok(vec)
            //     }
            // };
            return Ok(String::from("Test"))
        }
    }

    /// Unit tests in Rust are normally defined within such a `#[cfg(test)]`
    /// module and test functions are marked with a `#[test]` attribute.
    /// The below code is technically just normal Rust code.
    #[cfg(test)]
    mod tests {
        /// Imports all the definitions from the outer scope so we can use them here.
        use super::*;

        /// Imports `ink_lang` so we can use `#[ink::test]`.
        use ink_lang as ink;

        /// We test if the default constructor does its job.
        #[ink::test]
        fn default_works() {
            let _mycontract = Mycontract::default();
        }
    }
}
```

**`i try this, but there are some errors`**

```rs
error[E0599]: the method `get` exists for struct `ink_storage::Mapping<std::string::String, std::vec::Vec<ink_storage::Mapping<std::string::String, std::string::String>>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> lib.rs:30:39
   |
30 |               match self.hash_value_map.get(&key_value) {
   |                                         ^^^ method cannot be called on `ink_storage::Mapping<std::string::String, std::vec::Vec<ink_storage::Mapping<std::string::String, std::string::String>>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `std::vec::Vec<ink_storage::Mapping<std::string::String, std::string::String>>: ink_storage::traits::PackedLayout`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `mycontract` due to previous error
Error: Compilation failed with toolchain `nightly-2022-06-30-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

Caused by:
    command failed: "cargo" "check" "--target-dir" "/root/mycontract/target/dylint/target/nightly-2022-06-30-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "--manifest-path" "/root/mycontract/Cargo.toml"
ERROR: `"/root/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2022-12-24-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo" "dylint" "--lib" "ink_linting" "--manifest-path=/root/mycontract/Cargo.toml"` failed with exit code: Some(1)
```

Comment: mapping inside mapping is not possible in ink! contract. For the solution you can follow this [link](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3993/2844)